# C++ JSON Serialization, Proto-buf style

Tags: c++, json, serialization

I want to serialize several C++ objects into JSON, and deserialize them back. Obviously since C++ is lacking reflection, this can't be done automatically. I will need to somehow tell the serializer which data member goes into which JSON property.

I can do that with C++, but I'd rather use something like Protobuf's `message` to specify the mapping. Out of the many many JSON C++ libraries out there, is there one that support some sort of metadata that allows me to map the serialization process without implementing it myself?

Comment: boost serialization library is worth to try

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't create JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the JSON cpp or C files and use them as API. That is what I have done for my previous project. C++ does not come with inbuilt JSON support like JAVA. 
So include the files and use the JSON function as APIs. You can build it separately and link it statically to your program. Go to the JSON home page for language wise files:

http://json.org/

For CPP files:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/

i think its moved to git repo. The link is present there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but as I have said, I'd rather have the C++<-->JSON mapping defined in metadata instead of actual C++ code. If I can't find something that does this, I'll write it myself as you have suggested.

Comment: @zmbq : When I was searching last year, I was not able to find any repo which defines the JSON for C++ in metadata. This was the best possible solution I could find. If you find such please let me know also :)

Answer (score 0):

The ASN.1 tools from OSS Nokalva support JSON encoding rules for ASN.1 schemae.

You write an ASN.1 schema (protobufs schema are similar but inferior), compile it to whatever language you want (C++ in your case), and you get the bunch of classes that can serialise to/from JSON.

Not free I'm afraid.

ASN.1 is great - there's all sorts of encoding rules to suit all occasions.